# update deeply nested array mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I want to push one value in attachments array using mongodb. I want to update query using following criteria.

_id:ObjectId("5b56bd2f3e18580edc85af73") "cardID": ObjectId("5b56c895d0a04836f71aa776") "commentId":"2"

I want to push value in attachments, any help would be appreciated

This is a collection object:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b56bd2f3e18580edc85af73"),
            "orgId" : "90",
            "createdBy" : "test",
            "name" : "testname",
            "Cards" : [ 
                {
                    "cardID" : ObjectId("5b56c895d0a04836f71aa776"),
                    "cardName" : "test Name",
                    "cardCreated" : "",
                    "reviewer" : "",
                    "priority" : "",
                    "cardPosition" : "",
                    "membersAssigned" : [ 
                        "ggg", 
                        "fff"
                    ],
                    "labels" : [ 
                        "l1", 
                        "l2"
                    ],
                    "description" : "",
                    "attachements" : [],
                    "comments" : [ 
                        {
                            "commentId" : "2",
                            "commentedBy" : "test",
                            "date" : "",
                            "comment" : "Hello world",
                            "attachements" : [   
                                "1", 
                                "data"
                            ],
                            "emojis" : [ 
                                ":smile:", 
                                ":thumbsup:"
                            ],
                            "updatedBy" : "arkadata",
                            "updatedOn" : "",
                            "subComments" : {
                                "commentedBy" : "jaril",
                                "date" : "",
                                "comment" : "Hello world inside dark"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "commentId" : "3",
                            "commentedBy" : "test",
                            "date" : "",
                            "comment" : "Hello world",
                            "attachements" : [ 
                               "1",
                               "raj"
                            ],
                            "emojis" : [ 
                                ":smile:", 
                                ":thumbsup:"
                            ],
                            "updatedBy" : "arkadata",
                            "updatedOn" : "",
                            "subComments" : {
                                "commentedBy" : "jaril",
                                "date" : "",
                                "comment" : "Hello world inside dark"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "commentId" : 6.0
                        }
                    ],
                    "dueDate" : "",
                    "createdDate" : "",
                    "lastUpdated" : "",
                    "checkList" : [],
                    "position" : "5",
                    "status" : "active"
                },
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-07-24T05:46:23.890Z")
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with mongodb 3.6 `arrayFilters`

```
db.collection.update(
  { "_id": ObjectId(5b56bd2f3e18580edc85af73) },
  { "$push": { "Cards.$[card].comments.$[comment].attachments": "2" } },
  { "arrayFilters": { "card.cardID": ObjectId("5b56c895d0a04836f71aa776"), "comment.commentId": 2 } }
)
```

Make sure you cast your ids to ObjectId

#### Edit:

```
db.collection.update(
  { "_id": ObjectId(5b56bd2f3e18580edc85af73) },
  { "$push": { "Cards.$[card].comments.$[comment].attachments": "2" } },
  { "arrayFilters": [
    { "card.cardID": ObjectId("5b56c895d0a04836f71aa776")},
    {"comment.commentId": 2 }
    ]
  }
)
```