# MongoDB and Flask - Updating objects in a document's array (nested updating)

Tags: mongodb, flask

Assume we have following collection.

```
{
    "Region":"Karnataka",
    "ShortCode":"KA",
    "SubRegion":[
        {
            "District":"Banglore",
            "Commodity":[
                {
                    "Name":"items",
                    "isActive":true,
                    "CommoditySubType":[
                        {
                            "Title":"Moistouriser",
                            "isActive":true,
                            "hasGrades":true,
                            "Grade":[
                                {
                                    "Title":"Premium",
                                    "Rate":"150",
                                    "isActive":true,
                                    "hasRates":true,
                                    "hasSizes":true,
                                    "StartDate":"2021-03-31",
                                    "EndDate":"2021-04-06",
                                    "StartTime":"9:00am",
                                    "EndTime":"6:00pm",
                                    "Sizes":[
                                        {
                                            "Title":"Small",
                                            "isActive":true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                    "LastSevenDaysDates":[{
                                    "Date":2021-03-31,
                                    "Price":"150"
                                    }]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
         "District":"Coorg",
            "Commodity":[]
        }
    ] }
```

I want to update an object under LastsevndayDates. I tried this.

```
    mongo.db.supplierDailyPrice.update(
{ 
    "Region":region,
    "SubRegion.District":district,
    "SubRegion.Commodity.Name":commodity,
    "SubRegion.Commodity.CommoditySubType.Title":commoditysubtype,
    "$and": [
        { "SubRegion.Commodity.CommoditySubType.Grade": { "$exists": True}},
        { "SubRegion.Commodity.CommoditySubType.Grade.Title": "Premium" },
        ]      
},
{
    "$set": {
        "SubRegion.$[].Commodity.$[].CommoditySubType.$[].Grade.$[].LastSevenDaysDates": Date
       
    }
})
```

But it's failing with the error **pymongo.errors.WriteError: The path 'SubRegion.0.Commodity.0.CommoditySubType.1.Grade' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrayFilters to solve your problem

```
db.supplierDailyPrice.update({
    "Region":region
},
{
    $set:{
        "Subregion.$[sub].Commodity.$[com].CommoditySubType.$[Cst].Grade.$[grd]. LastSevenDaysDates.$[sev].date": Date
    }
},
{
    array_filter : [
      {"sub.district": district},
      {"com.name": commodity},
      {"Cst.title": commoditysubtype},
      {"grd.title": "premium"},
      {"sev.price":"150"},
    ]
})
```

Not tested the code but something like this will solve your problem. For more reference you can check out the links below:

[Update deeply nested array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706647/update-deeply-nested-array-in-mongodb)

[update deeply nested array mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495664/update-deeply-nested-array-mongodb)

[Pymongo error for ArrayFilters to update multiple subdocuments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60862120/pymongo-error-for-arrayfilters-to-update-multiple-subdocuments)

Answer (score 0):

Ujjwal's answer is on the right track.  I fixed a few typos.

More information here about $[] usage.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/
https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/update-array-elements-document-mql-positional-operators/

```json
    db.supplierDailyPrice.update_one({
        "Region": region
    },
    {
        $set:{
            "SubRegion.$[sub].Commodity.$[com].CommoditySubType.$[cst].Grade.$[grd].LastSevenDaysDates.$[sev].Date": "2021-04-03"
        }
    },
    {
        "array_filters" : [
          {"sub.District": district},
          {"com.Name": commodity},
          {"cst.Title": commoditysubtype},
          {"grd.Title": grade},
          {"sev.Price":"150"},
        ]
    },
    {
       upsert=true
    }
)
```